# Code to take hindi text and save to mysql using ajax post method

Tags: ajax, jsp, utf-8

I want to save Hindi text in database using jsp. Inside JSP, I have to use ajax post method. But on Servlet controller when I try to get that parameter and print on console then it's displaying ????????

Comment: hey @Hemant did you find anything or any way around? Please let me know as i'm facing this situation.